# Display JSON items of number element

Tags: json, angular

I have a json data and I would like to display items of json data, but I cannot reach phone.0 element while reaching **phone.snippet** or **phone.age** and it gives error **" Parser Error: Unexpected token '0'  "**
Here is my code;

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let phone of phones">
      {{ phone.age }}
    </li>
  </ul>

 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let phone of phones">
      {{ phone.0 }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And .ts file

```
export class AppComponent  {

    phones = [{
        "0": "Nexus S",
  "snippet": "Fast just got faster with Nexus S.",
     "age": 0
    }];

}
```

Comment: try phone['0']. tip: in general is a "bad idea" the name of a propertie was a number

Comment: it comes from webservice and I have no permission to change this. This is coming data for an example, so I tried but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access '0' property like this :

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let phone of phones">
    {{ phone.age }}
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let phone of phones">
    {{ phone[0] }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let phone of phones">
      {{ phone.age }}
    </li>
  </ul>

 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let phone of phones">
      {{ phone[0] }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

use `{{ phone["0"]}}` for that

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let phone of phones">
    {{ phone.age }}
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let phone of phones">
    {{ phone["0"]}}
  </li>
</ul>
```